# Change select box value depending other selected option box wordpress

Tags: wordpress

1. I want to create a select box in WordPress, with 3 option
   Option no 1 is Male,
   option no 2 is Female,
   Option no 3 is Transgender

if I select the Male option it shows "Hi I am Male'"

If I select the Female  option it shows " Hi I am female"

If I select the Transgender option it shows "Hi I am transgender"

Please anyone help me to create this

```
<select name="select_value">
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="other">Others</option>
</select>


if($_POST['select_value'] == 'male') {
  //do something
  echo "Hi, I am Male";
} else {
  echo "Hi, I am Female";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <select name="select_value" id="selectvalue">
  <option value="Hi I am Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Hi I am female">Female</option>
  <option value="Hi I am transgender">Others</option>
</select>

    <h6></h6>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
 
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#selectvalue').on('change',function(){
        var selev = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('h6').html(''+ selev +'');
      });
 
   });
 
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check below code i think helpfull